# Restore or convert file.dump into pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, dump, pgadmin, navicat

I have a problem with a dump file that client give me to make a file to connect with postgres database in php, and I do this first

1. Rename this file **ssdf_master.dump** to **ssdf_master.sql** to execute in pgAdmin or Navicat but doesn't work.
2. Run this pg_restore **ssdf_master.dump** and ask for a password and type password that I save in pgAdmin but not.

My ssdf_master.dump has characteres like \N and . and when run that file in navicat display this error:

```
[Err] ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «01»
LINE 784: 01 Aguascalientes AGS 00000 99999 \N
```

**Extract of file**

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'LATIN1';
SET standard_conforming_strings = off;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET escape_string_warning = off;

--
-- Name: plpgsql; Type: PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE; Schema: -; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE plpgsql;


ALTER PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE plpgsql OWNER TO postgres;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: scg; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE scg (
    base_datos character varying(8),
    ip character varying(15),
    tipo character(1),
    owner character varying(8),
    own_passwd character varying(8)
);


ALTER TABLE public.scg OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Data for Name: scg; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COPY scg (base_datos, ip, tipo, owner, own_passwd) FROM stdin;
SCGDGCA 10.18.20.150    E   postgres    postgres
SCGSJ   10.18.20.150    E   postgres    postgres
SCGDPRE 10.18.20.150    E   postgres    postgres
SCGDSSA 10.18.20.150    E   postgres    postgres
SCGDAFI 10.18.20.150    E   postgres    postgres
SCGSDA  10.18.20.150    E   postgres    postgres
SCGDPRED    10.18.20.150    E   postgres    postgres
\.
```

Note: Previously, I create a database called **postgres** with user **postgres** without pasword.

I hope I have explained!

Comment: serverfault.com might be a good place to ask too

Comment: Thanks, I've put in there place too!

Comment: Cross-posted here: http://serverfault.com/q/491364/102814 but be nice, SoldierCorp was kind of told to.

Comment: 1. You need to actually look at the contents of the file, say the first 50 lines, to find out what's inside. Add them to the question if it doesn't make sense to you. 2. Use the command line `psql` instead of a GUI, it's simpler for that kind of task.

Comment: @DanielVérité I posted a extract of file... and regarding use psql, I used but dont insert table and data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the extract of the file, this is a dump in plain text format.

It should not to be passed to pg_restore because:

> pg_restore is a utility for restoring a PostgreSQL database from an
>   archive created by pg_dump(1) in one of the non-plain-text formats

Rather it should be fed directly to `psql` when connected to an already created database, presumably empty. The objects seem to be owned by `postgres`, so this should do:

```
psql -U postgres -d yourdbname < dumpfile
```

Comment: Sorry for late... I think works but amm check the database and the tables had been inserted avoiding errors, I don't understand! and when run your line "psql -U...." display something like this: Error: La relacón "scg" ya existe"

Comment: Errors about already existing objects would happen when you restore into a non-empty database. The non-empty database would happen because of previous restores that failed half-way. You can drop and recreate the database before importing into it.

Comment: IN windows is to hard to configure, in Linux is easy and your line works, thanks.